# How to change the default "non_field_errors" message with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to change the default error message value of a "non field error" in a serializer. Here's what I've got so far:

```py
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {
            "non_field_errors": {
                "error_messages": {
                    "unique": "There exists an item with this name already!"
                }
            }
        }
```

`ItemSerializer` behaves as expected, but the code above has no effect on the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default error message of `non_field_errors` by adding a `UniqueTogetherValidator` in `validators` (inside your `Meta` class) like so:

```py
validators = [
      UniqueTogetherValidator(
       queryset=Item.objects.all(),
       fields=["org", "item_name"],
       message="Duplicate items!",
     )
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY in REST framework setting.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY': 'your_key_here',
}
```

Comment: Am I supposed to put my error messages there? According to the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#non_field_errors_key ) NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY defaults to non_field_errors, so by my understanding of it, changing it doesn't make any difference.